# Excel C API: Is there an Excel v4.0 macro function to test if a sheet is hidden?

Tags: c++, excel-addins, xll, excel-4.0

I need to find out if a sheet is hidden using an Excel 4 macro function / Excel SDK, preferably getting XlSheetVisibility value (i.e. `xlSheetHidden`, `xlSheetVeryHidden`, `xlSheetVisible`).

I would expect this kind of query to be possible by `GET.DOCUMENT()` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I also looked into `GET.WORKBOOK()` and `GET.WORKSPACE()` to no avail.

Is there a way to do this thru a macro function without resorting to VBA?

Comment: I don't know anything about Office addins but there should be `get_Visbible()` method for Excel sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET.WORKBOOK(38)` returns the name of the active sheet.

Hidden sheets can't be activated.

So, first call `WORKBOOK.SELECT("sheetname", "sheetname")` to select the desired sheet and attempt to make it active. If that sheet is hidden, it will fail and the active sheet won't change. Then call `GET_WORKBOOK(38)` to get the name of the current active sheet. If it's "sheetname" then it's not hidden.

Unfortunately this doesn't distinguish between hidden and veryHidden.